# How to use JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON file :

```
{
    "player1" : [
        "kills" : 0,
        "deaths" : 0,
        "wins" : 0
    ],
    "player2" : [
        "kills" : 0,
        "deaths" : 0,
        "wins" : 0
    ]
}
```

But i don't no how use it. I do not know how to call the file, I tried with a parser but I did not succeed.
I would like to use that in a Java program.

Can someone help me and at the same time explain to me?

Comment: In which you want to use JSON, it is used everywhere

Comment: This is not valid JSON.  I'm not surprised a JSON parser won't accept it.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: See this : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the whole file and save it to string
2. Now create the JSONObject using that string

   JSONObject x = new JSONObject(string);

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson lib to convert your Json file to Java Object.

Lets Assume your file is
Player.json

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
InputStream is = Player.class.getResourceAsStream("/Player.json");
playerObj = mapper.readValue(is, Player.class);`